# What is window load alternative?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a following situation: I want to **show** my images **at once** only when the page is fully loaded because I want to avoid showing images one by one inside ***document ready function*** (they are initially hidden and want to show them **at once** only when document is finished loading), so I am using`$(window).load(function () {});`

When I use this function it runs fine and behaves as expected, but my only problem is that load function is  **deprecated**.  
For example if I use the code below **without** `$(window).load` i can see my images loaded one by one which is not an option (setTimeout is no option either).  
My question: How can I achieve the same behavior without using `$(window).load`? Thank you!!

Sample code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 //on document ready HIDE my images 
glowHide.hide();

   //on page LOAD show all images AT ONCE (works fine but depreciated) 
   $(window).load(function(){
   glowHide.show();
   });

});
```

Comment: So you want to show all images at once, only when all the images have been loaded fully?

Comment: Not something you should worry about. Serve up valid HTML and let the browser decide how best to load its images.

Comment: Yes that is what i want to do! My code is working good but load is depreciated:(

Comment: Can you do `$(window).on("load", function(){...})`? I've not tried it, but `on` would bind the load event to the window. Figured it may be worth a shot =\

Comment: I might try your suggestion Chase THX;)

Comment: Hope it works for you! Please let me know either way, I would like to know =)

Comment: Working even in IE8 THX Chase!!

Comment: @Chase You should post that as an answer so that it can be marked as answered and get removed from the unanswered list. Using .on or .bind would be the way to do it if .load is removed.

Comment: Thanks @KevinB, I'll do that! I honestly had kinda forgotten about it to be honest since I hadn't received an alert or anything regarding the question.

Comment: @Chase no problem, i just happen to come across it while looking through the unanswereds, :p

Comment: @DejoDekic, glad it helped and everything is working =)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To bind the `load` event to the window, you should use the [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method provided by jQuery.

> The .on() method attaches event handlers to the currently selected set
>   of elements in the jQuery object. As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method
>   provides all functionality required for attaching event handlers.

```
$(window).on("load", function(){...})
```