# if $(window).load() is deprecated, what should I use?

Tags: jquery, html, load

I need a function that is called when the page is totally loaded (text, image, and so on).

I noticed that `$(window).load()` is now deprecated. So, what should I use?

Comment: `$(window).on("load", function(){...})` :: Going off this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12746566/what-is-window-load-alternative

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12746566/what-is-window-load-alternative  duplicate

Comment: @dystroy: http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Comment: @dystroy http://api.jquery.com/load-event/, **version deprecated: 1.8**

Comment: @markzzz Well seen. Now, why was it deprecated ? Just because it was a shortcut with an alternative (on) ?

Comment: @dystroy here's the report from the deprecation in 1.8 http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11733 appears to be just to prevent confusion.

Comment: @Liam Thanks. Makes sense as it **is** confusing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [load() method deprecated?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12643160/load-method-deprecated)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you want just avoid the `load` function, use the generic `on` function :

```
$(window).on('load', function(){
  // insert code here
});
```

Comment: That missing `)` is messing with my OCD.

Comment: @DJDavid98 Are you better with a missing `}` ?

Comment: .load() should be a shortcut for on(load) I guess? So why deprecate it?

Comment: @markzzz http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11733 explains that it is ambiguous between on('load', function) and the ajax .load() methods.